# How can I add the same login form as a modal on multiple pages using Flask-WTF and Jinja2?

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I would like to have a button in a Navbar which opens a modal to a login form: a simple form with an email field and a password field. Within the modal body, my HTML looks like:

```
<form role="form" action="/login/"method="post" name="login">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.email(class_="form-control", placeholder="Email") }}
        {{ form.password(class_="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}

        <input class="form-control" type="submit" placeholder="Login"></input>
</form>
```

However, the Jinja2 templating engine doesn't recognise form, as it isn't specified in render_template:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('landing.html', title='Home')
```

Is there a way I can display the form on `landing.html` (and other pages), without having to replicate the form code for each view (which seems very inefficient)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to write some javascript to make an AJAX call to hit an endpoint (a new views.py route) which will return the rendered HTML login template (your modal login dialog).  It could even be the same endpoint you POST to.

In views.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('landing.html', title='Home')


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        # Use werkzeug to validate user's password etc.
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            if login_user(user):
                flash('You\'re now logged in!')
                return redirect(url_for('hello'))

    return render_template('login_modal.html', form=form)
```

... and while I can't provide specifics here (it would vary according to your JS framework), you would then need to add Javascript to your base template file which would do the following:

```
# If user not authenticated:
#    Hit /login/ via AJAX to fetch a copy of the rendered login form
#    Insert it into the DOM, presumably into the modal dialog
```

When an unauthenticated user submits the form, it'll then POST to `/login/`, where you'll need appropriate code to handle the login.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Do you mind explaining further?

Comment: sure, I've fleshed it out a bit.  hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much :) I've marked this answer as correct (although I can't up vote due to a lack of points).